# Java command line input with heredoc

Tags: java, input, command-line, heredoc

I have a frustratingly simple problem: I need to write a program that accepts input of the form:

```
cat << EOF | java myProgram.java
> 1 2 3 4
> 5 6 7 8
> etcetera
> EOF
```

But my args[] is always empty when I try to do anything with it in main(). Even `cat << EOF | echo` followed by input doesn't produce any output at the terminal. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The code isn't the problem - it's just accessing the input. Here's the code though: 
`public static void main(String args[]){
 for (String line : args){
     System.out.println(line);
 }
}
`
This outputs nothing, as args[] is an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide any arguments to the program, so of course `args[]` is empty.

You can read the heredoc from `System.in`.

You seem confused about the difference between arguments (`args[]`) and `stdin` (`System.in`).

`echo` writes its *arguments* (`args[]`) to `stdout`, e.g.:

```
$ echo foo bar
foo bar
```

`cat` writes its `stdin` (`System.in`) to `stdout`, e.g.:

```
$ cat << EOF
> foo bar
> EOF
foo bar
```

or

```
$ echo foo bar | cat     # Useless use of cat
foo bar
```

Your `cat << EOF | echo` example doesn't work because `echo` does not read `stdin`.

Also, your use of `cat` is useless. You can just write

```
$ java myProgram.java << EOF
> 1 2 3 4
> 5 6 7 8
> etcetera
> EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining - I've never seen cat used in this way before, but that's just what I'm required to deal with. I was running into confusion because I thought the concatenated heredoc would be fed into the command line immediately after the `java MyProgram` call as command line arguments, not piped into standard in.

Comment: If you need them as arguments, just provide them as arguments. Must be far simpler. Or use `xargs`, which takes `stdin` and uses it as arguments for something else.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [standard input stream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
  String line = null;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
  reader.close();
  inputReader.close();
}
```

Comment: I know how to use all of that fine - the program I'm writing requires input in this form, since it's going to be evaluated using automated data entry.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out; like I said below, this question was the result of not knowing how the heredoc was made accessible to my program.